# Keyset is not defined with smart card and service in Windows Server 2008/2012

Tags: delphi, service, windows-server-2008, smartcard, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to use the Capicom API and the MSXML5 API to sign a XML with a certificate stored in a smartcard within a service application running under Windows Server 2008 or 2012. It works fine when I'm testing in Windows 8 or as application, but as service it fails with the error Keyset is not defined.

The method that fails is `createKeyFromCSP` from the `IXMLDigitalSignature` interface of the `MSXML5.DLL`.

Some points I've tried so far :

- Tried with the smart card through WTS and in the server machine. Failed in both cases.
- Checked drivers and funcionality of the smart card reader. I think that there are not problems here, because it works fine as application, as I've said.
- Changing the `CAPICOM` store openning flag `CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE` to `CAPICOM_SMART_CARD_USER_STORE`. It fails and doesn't find any certificates even with current user credentials informed in service properties in `services.msc`.
- Starting the service as Local System and impersonate the current user with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` flag. Failed too.
- Giving permission to the event `Global\Microsoft Smart Card Resource Manager Started` through the use of the ACL API and `AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor` (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2011/05/19/scardestablishcontext-fails-with-scard_e_no_service-error/). Failed.
- Looking for permissions for the private keys in certificate manager console, but as the private key of the certificate is within the smart card, I couldn't find any option to set permissions to specific users.
- Giving permissions to all users for the folders under `C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto` (Administrador is the current user). Failed.

Debugging with the WinDbg debugger, I've seen that the problem is within the said method `createKeyFromCSP`. It calls internally an CryptoAPI method called `CryptAcquireContext` and this method fails returning the said error (`NTE_KEYSET_NOTDEF` or Keyset is not defined).

From my search, I think it should be some permission issue implemented from Windows Server 2008, however I couldn't find any more things that could cause this problem. Does anyone knows what could be causing this error and if it's some configuration that I could do in the system to solve this error?

PS: I'm working with delphi, so the solution couldn't use any .NET solutions. It could be avaliable through some WinAPI, however.

Comment: How do you expect to enter pin when you are running as a service with no desktop to show pin dialog? Certificate is usually propagated to CurrentUser store but you are using LocalSystem to run the service. It could work if you manually move certificate from CurrentUser to LocalMachine. But the real problem is entering pin.

Comment: Hi @pepo, the pin isn't the problem here. I inform the pin through the CryptSetProvParam function with the param PP_SIGNATURE_PIN and it works fine as desktop application as I said. I also know about the propagation of the certificate, and that's the reason I use some user account (not the default LocalSystem nor the LocalService account), in my tests with administrative rights, to execute the service. I inform the account in the service properties.

Comment: Try to manually move certificate from CurrentUser to LocalMachine and set the service to run as LocalSystem. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I don't have the smart card here right now, but as soon as possible I'll try this. Thanks.